# SQL query to remove the preceeding and appended text

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'm building a query to run against a database by appending user entered data with some additional information like this:

```
SELECT * FROM vBranch  WHERE (((BranchIsActive = 'Yes' AND BranchIsValid = 
'Yes') AND BranchIsInternational = 'Yes' AND 1=2) AND 
vBranch.BranchSecurityGroup=1).
```

This part:

```
SELECT * FROM vBranch WHERE ((
```

is appended by me,

and this part:

```
(BranchIsActive = 'Yes' AND BranchIsValid = 'Yes') AND BranchIsInternational 
= 'Yes'
```

is the user entered value

and this part:

```
AND 1=2) AND vBranch.BranchSecurityGroup=1)
```

is also appended by me.

What my doubt is whether the user can write any query which excludes the string which i appended before and after the user entered data and execute only the data which the user entered against the database? Is it possible? 
One thing to note is that i've restricted few DML and DDL statements too except the "select" statement since i'm building a "select" statement to execute against the database.

Comment: How is the text entered by the user? if it's entered in a textbox, just ending the string with ))'-- will cause the engine to ignore the rest of the command. Needless to say, that is SQL-Injection, and it's a very bad thing.

Comment: Yeah the user enters the values through a text box. My intention is to prevent SQL injection. So i wanted to know if it is possible for the user to enter a query in the text box which removes the string which i append to it.

Comment: Also the SQL query will be validated before it is run against the database. So the query entered by the user should be a valid SQL query.

Comment: It's almost impossible to prevent SQL Injection in that scenario. Restricting the user to issue only `select` helps, but as long as that text box is up there, consider that **all** your data is in full view of the malicious user.

Comment: Hmm.. So you mean to say that the user can write a valid SQL query which neglects the appended string and execute only that part? Is there any delimiter in SQL which can do that?

Comment: In your case `1=1))'--` could give the user all data. This is just an example, it's by no means the only thing a malicious user could do.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what you have in front of your SQL statement. As long as you execute your sql as a dynamic statement it's a high candidate for SQL injection as already pointed by SWeko. You can try it out for yourself. Create a table named "DeleteMe". Then enter the following in your textbox: `1=1));DROP TABLE DeleteMe;--`; Then check your database and see that DeleteMe table is gone.

Additionally, while this does not answer your question, I am concerned about the "1=2" in your query. It will almost certainly yields no result, hope that is just a "not good example".

Comment: Yeah you are right. But i'm allowing only "select" command to be entered by the user, rest of them like "drop, delete, truncate" are considered as invalid query and the process halts.

Comment: And yes, 1=1)) would give all the data. But i'm appending 1=2 in all the cases. Would that matter? Or can the user enter a query in the text box with 1=1 and get all the data? I'm not so good with SQL. So asking too many questions. Please don't mind :)

Comment: That's just one example and as Sweko already pointed out "it's by no means the only thing malcious users could do". So someone can enter in the tetxbox: 1=1));update vBranch set BranchIsActive ='No'; and the list could go on really. 

*Added tip. You may have forgotten to restrict the "database user" to that database alone and it can query system tables. So users from your UI can enter 1=1));SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins-- (for SQL server). That's pretty dangerous too.

Comment: ahh this is a good point. I will have to reconsider my implementation. Thanks for the replies. Will update if i find anything else.